# Update PPT Charts from Excel is not working for MS Office Standard Version

Tags: excel, windows, powerpoint

I have a code that puts data from `Excel` into `PowerPoint` to update a Chart. The data is put into the excel file that lies behind the chart. After closing the excel file the chart is updated and everything is fine.

In our company we work with different office versions and this works perfectly for

```
MS Office Home and Business 2016

MS Office Professional 2019

MS Office Professional Plus 2016
```

But not for `MS Standard 2019`. In this case the charts just get not updated. The code we are using to accomplish this is:

```
Sub Chart_copy_gs(ByRef objpresentation As PowerPoint.Presentation, ByVal blattname As String, ByVal slideNr As Integer, ByVal chartName As String)
   
    Set ObjSlide = objpresentation.Slides(slideNr)
    ObjSlide.Select
    Set mychart = ObjSlide.Shapes(chartName).Chart
    
        Set wb = mychart.ChartData.Workbook
        Set WS = wb.Worksheets(1)
    
        WS.Range("A1:F40").ClearContents
        WS.Range("A1:F40").value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(blattname).Range("A45:F82").value
        
       wb.Close True
        
    Set ObjSlide = objpresentation.Slides(slideNr)
    Set mychart = ObjSlide.Shapes(chartName).Chart
     
        Set wb = mychart.ChartData.Workbook
        Set WS = wb.Worksheets(1)
        
        WS.Range("A1").ClearContents
    
    wb.Close True
    
End Sub
```

But the problem cannot lie within the code since it works fine for the above mentioned versions of office. Anyone who has an idea what the problem could be here?

Comment: after you run the code, when you go to the powerpoint and look at  the embeded excel it shows the old values?

Comment: exactly. the values are not updated.

Comment: when you debug and step through the code do you see the new values in ```ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(blattname).Range("A45:F82").value``` ?. I am just wondering if "ThisWorkbook" is visible in your function. Can you try to pass "ThisWorkbook" ByRef as well to the function input paraments?  What you can also try is after line 5 to insert the following code  "mychart.ChartData.Activate".